# EasyMock 3.2: Creating an expect() for a method that takes a generic as an argument

Tags: easymock

In one of my mocked classes, I need to create an `expect` for a method with a signature similar to this:

```
public <T extends Object> T createInitInstance(Class<T> cast)
```

What I return will differ based on the `cast` argument. It will be another mocked object, of the type specified by `cast`. Some of the ways I've tried are:

```
expect(core.createInitInstance(anyObject(QueryParserPlugin.class))).andReturn(queryPlugin);
```

and

```
expect(core.createInitInstance(isA(QueryParserPlugin.class))).andReturn(queryPlugin);
```

and

```
expect(core.createInitInstance(isA(Class.class))).andReturn(queryPlugin);
```

Where `queryPlugin` is a mock of the class `QueryParserPlugin`. The first two give a compiler error, saying:

```
required: Class<T>
found: QueryParserPlugin
```

The third one compiles, but always returns a null, probably because it's not matching the expect, and the mock was created with `createNiceMock`.

Any idea how I can correctly specify the parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This ended up being a Java question rather than an EasyMock one, but this is what worked:

```
expect(core.createInitInstance(isA(QueryParserPlugin.class.getClass()))).andReturn(queryPlugin);
```